# Should I create a new actor every time or create it as static earlier

Tags: akka, actor, akka.net, akka-actor

I use akka.net and a memory leak may occurred because it cost a lot of memory and increase all the time

Should I create a new actor every time or create it as static earlier?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of further context:

Actors by themselves are lightweight and quick to create, so feel free to create them as and when you want. 
When you're finished with them, make sure you get rid of them with a Context.Stop(Self) (or one of the alternative ways of stopping an actor).